# join over four tables does not produce excepted output

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy version

```
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
SQLAlchemy==1.1.3
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.32.11
```

I got following query which produces the results I would like to see. Joining the translation_producttable to get the translation according to the selected language. In summary there are three languges available in the translation table joined on language_code

```
$ docker_sql.sh "select sizename,orderid, product_translation.pid, language_code, totalamount  from customerorders JOIN itemsbought ON customerorders.id = itemsbought.orderid INNER JOIN panties ON panties.id = itemsbought.productid JOIN product_translation ON product_translation.pid = panties.id JOIN productsizes ON productsizes.sizeid = panties.sizeid where language_code = 'de' and customerorders.id= 13155 ;"
+----------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+
| sizename | orderid | pid   | language_code | totalamount |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+
| L        |   13155 | 40338 | de            |         144 |
| L        |   13155 | 45058 | de            |         144 |
| L        |   13155 | 45060 | de            |         144 |
| L        |   13155 | 45079 | de            |         144 |
| L        |   13155 | 46063 | de            |         144 |
| L        |   13155 | 46070 | de            |         144 |
+----------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+
```

When I try to do the same in python with sqlalchemy

```
    self.orders = self.orders.filter(CustomerOrders.id==13155)
        self.orders = self.orders.join(ProductTranslation, ProductTranslation.language_code==self.lang)
        self.orders = self.orders.options(
                joinedload(CustomerOrders.items).\
                joinedload(Itemsbought.panties, Itemsbought.productid==Products.id).\
                joinedload(Products.translation, ProductTranslation.language_code==self.lang)
            )
 
        self.orders = self.orders.filter(
                Itemsbought.orderid==CustomerOrders.id,
                Itemsbought.productid==ProductTranslation.pid,
                ProductTranslation.language_code=='de',
 
                )
 
 
        self.orders = self.orders.paginate(per_page=5)
        print(self.orders.query)
        for o in self.orders.items:
 
            print("################### ORDER #####################")
            print(o)
            print("################### ORDER END#####################")
 
            for i in o.items:
                print(i.panties.translation)
                for pt in i.panties.translation:
                    if pt.language_code == self.lang:
                        i.panties.pt = pt
```

it produces ( since there are three languages active )

```
# OUTPUT
 
fasty        | SELECT customerorders.id AS customerorders_id, ................ ENTIRE_CUSTOMERTABLE columns..... 
ITEMSBOUGHT_COLUMNS etc... 
fasty        | FROM itemsbought, customerorders INNER JOIN product_translation ON product_translation.language_code = %s LEFT OUTER JOIN itemsbought AS itemsbought_1 ON customerorders.id = itemsbought_1.orderid LEFT OUTER JOIN panties AS panties_1 ON panties_1.id = itemsbought_1.productid LEFT OUTER JOIN product_translation AS product_translation_1 ON product_translation_1.pid = panties_1.id 
fasty        | WHERE customerorders.hashcode = %s AND itemsbought.orderid = customerorders.id AND itemsbought.productid = product_translation.pid AND product_translation.language_code = %s
fasty        | ################### ORDER #####################
fasty        | <fasty.models.CustomerOrders object at 0x7f4b3492bc50>
fasty        | ################### ORDER END#####################
fasty        | [<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b3492b250>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b3492b050>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b3492b0d0>]
fasty        | [<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34934d50>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34934a50>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34934ad0>]
fasty        | [<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34934590>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b349344d0>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34934350>]
fasty        | [<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34b976d0>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a740d0>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a74190>]
fasty        | [<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a88090>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a88210>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a88a10>]
fasty        | [<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a178d0>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a17cd0>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7f4b34a17d50>]
```

How would I put it that way, that I get order.translation.name and not all results for the translation_table?
like:

```
<fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7fb45a972b10>, <fasty.models.ProductTranslation object at 0x7fb45a972d10>]
```

I would expect this filter is enough? Since the printed query does exactly that

```
#FILTER:
                joinedload(Products.translation, ProductTranslation.language_code==self.lang),
```

while the printed query says to too?

```
...
WHERE customerorders.hashcode = %s AND itemsbought.orderid = customerorders.id AND 
itemsbought.productid = product_translation.pid AND product_translation.language_code = %s
```

How would I map this. Suggestion from the sqlalchemy chat already

```
1. reproduce the original query exactly using joins instead of joinedload and only fetching the needed columns
2. use joinedload and filter the languages in python
3. use contains_eager or similar to force the mapper to accept a filtered collection of languages

.. thoughts.
2 will be easiest with your existing query and probably most flexible. 1 is the most efficient if this is a hot query. 3 is a bit messy imo
```

1. I tried that without no result since I am lost while SQL-Alchemy prints the correct query for me. Furthermore it seems to be a mapping error maybe? Since with joinedload I do not have to put any "lazy"-method on th relationship configuration?
2. I would really like to not to that. I could use plain SQL then as well? Also that still would not help the still other join from products to productsizes, which I do not want to filter out in python too. I would like to see this as instance like you can access order.totalamount or order.itemsbought
3. I had same results for eager_loading. How should this change the output of the Queries

Help is really appreciated. I am kinda lost there.

Thanks